# Авторизация vk

Tags: php, вконтакте

Есть [сайт](http://naklikay.ru) и войти можно через вк. То есть когда заходишь, передаётся следующее:

> http://naklikay.ru/index.php?act=register&uid=123456&...

Когда прописываю у себя на сайте код:

```
<?
file_get_contents('http://naklikay.ru/index.php?act=register&...');
?>
```

То он тупо опять отображает эту форму входа. Одним словом, мне нужно авторизоваться со своего сайта, на их. Можете подсказать, как сделать верно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если это нужно только для одного аккаунта, можно сделать отчасти-вручную:

1. авторизоваться на том сайте через ваш аккаунт vk;
2. вытащить из браузера куки, связанные с тем сайтом и с ВКонтакте;
3. из Вашего php скрипта дергать ссылку не `file_get_contents`, а использовать [cURL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php) и подсовывать в запрос сохранённые в п.1 куки.

Answer (score 2):

Никак этого не сделать. Кнопки авторизации в ВК делаются яваскриптом, то есть получая одну лишь страницу через file get contents там не будет даже этой кнопки «Войти через ВКонтакте», она сгенерируется позже. Имитировать нажатие по ней уже не получится. А используя API ВКонтакте можно авторизоваться лишь для своего сайта, который нужно предварительно подключить и подтвердить под своё владение (насчёт последнего не уверен, но так должно быть). Если бы всё было так просто, то не было бы никакой безопасности.

Хотя, по сути то это и возможно, но при авторизации естественно есть хэш, в котором содержится URL сайта, с которого произвелась авторизация.

Comment: @dydydydym, а если например устанавливать куки, которые сохраняются при авторизации на сайте naklikay.ru? Хотя пробывал и ничего не вышло..

Comment: Там куки вроде для каждого сайта разные.

Answer (score 1):

Таким способом у вас вряд ли что-то получится. 
Вот [здесь](http://vk.com/developers.php?oid=-1&p=Auth) описано, как создать авторизацию на сайте через контакт

Comment: @atnartur, мне нужно со своего сайта авторизоваться к стороннему, где установлена форма авторизации от ВК.